# How to get environment variables from minidump?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, crash-dumps

I got a minidump (crash dump) created with `procdump -ma`. I can open that on VS2013 and WinDbg, however I need to know which environment variables were sent to that process. Is there a way of doing that without writing a memory parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Visual Studio** 2015 Community Edition,

1. open the dump via `File | Open | File ...`
2. start debugging by pressing the *Play* button
3. open a memory window from `Debug | Windows | Memory`
4. enter `$env` as address.
5. open the context menu of the memory window

   - select `No data`
   - select `Unicode text`

Unfortunately it is not possible to have the line breaks (which are `'\0'` / `0x00` actually) displayed correctly that way.

In **WinDbg**, as already mentioned in another answer, use `.symfix c:\symbols; .reload; !peb`.

Comment: If you have trouble with WinDbg and `!peb` on dumps at this time, see [known issue with symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278634/is-there-a-known-issue-relating-to-windows-7-kernel-symbols)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have proper symbols, `!peb` in windbg should get you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

**This works in Visual Studio 2017:**

1. go to a watch window
2. enter "$env"
3. press the  on the right