# C# Out of Memory exception while combining byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am getting out of memory exception while combing byte array of size 10MB until the main array of 500MB

The method I am using to combine byte array is:

```
private byte[] Combine(byte[] mainarray, byte[] newarray)
{
    byte[] c = new byte[mainarray.Length + newarray.Length];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(mainarray, 0, c, 0, mainarray.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(newarray, 0, c, mainarray.Length, newarray.Length);
    newarray = null;
    mainarray = null;
    return c;
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is the size of the arrays?

Comment: What do you mean by "until the main array of 500MB"? Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: 42. string [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) 42 long.

Comment: @rbm ;) thanks for clearing that up lol

Answer (score 4):

In a 32 bit application, it is likely that you get an OutOfMemoryException, because you have (if I understand that correctly)

- a source array of 10 MB
- another source array of 490 MB
- the destination array of 500 MB

Since arrays need to be contiguous in memory, .NET must be able to allocate a single large block of 500 MB, which is quite unlikely.

I'd like to demonstrate this in the debugger, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278634/is-there-a-known-issue-relating-to-windows-7-kernel-symbols) issue currently prevents me from doing it. The command in WinDbg is `!address -summary` and you need to look for the largest free block.

Basically it may look like this:

```
--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
<unclassified>                         6007          57a86000 (   1.370 Gb)  85.37%   68.48%
Free                                    268          19519000 ( 405.098 Mb)           19.78%

...

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
<unclassified>                               66f0000           c041000 ( 192.254 Mb)
Free                                        71c97000           4109000 (  65.035 Mb)
```

which means, there is 405 MB free, but only 65 MB in a single block.

Comment: Actually I am adding the 10MB of array's together until I can form a 500MB array, I can only read 10MB at one time but the final result needs to be a 500MB byte array, Any suggestion?