# How to install ndiskd extension for debugging my driver?

Tags: driver, windbg, ndis

I have a mini port network driver installed on my PC . I want to debug kernel mode to find the mistakes of my driver . i Know i can use `WinDbg` tool for getting logs but i heard about the `Ndiskd` extension . How to install this ? Is this a tool ? or can i use with `command prompt` or with `WinDbg` ? can i get setup by setup installation procedure ? what are the requirements needed ? i tried with WinDbg but i can't get the proper logs from that . So that's why i search on internet and got about the ndiskd .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ndiskd` is a debugger extension for WinDbg (or ntsd or kd, whatever you like most). Once you know this, it's just a matter on how to load the extension. There are three ways:

1. `.load ndiskd` if it is placed in WinDbgs extension directory, which it is by default on my WinDbg 6.2.9200 and 9.2.9600 installations (`winxp` subdirectory). Use `.extpath` to see which directories are searched by default.
2. `.load <full path\ndiskd.dll>`
3. `.loadby <reference module> ndiskd`

I never used the latter in kernel debugging, the only real benefit is in `.loadby sos clr`, so I guess you go with one of the first two options.

Once you have done that, you can access the `ndiskd` debugger extension by its `!`-commands. To explicitly call such a command, use

```
!ndiskd.<command>
```

e.g.

```
!ndiskd.miniport
```

Comment: And be sure you have [set up symbols correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Comment: but i can't locate ndiskd.dll in my PC

Comment: or i need to install WDK ? i install only Debugging tool for windows (x86)

Comment: Thanks lot ... i download from http://rxwen.blogspot.ca/2010/04/standalone-windbg-v6120002633.html  and i need to set symbol path to my .pdb files  ??

Comment: @roger: please get a newer version than 6.12. It's quite old, see [WinDbg versions](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/). Download links are available on [Codemachine](http://codemachine.com/downloads.html)

Comment: @roger: yes, regarding symbols, do `.symfix c:\symbols` and `.sympath+ c:\mysymbols`, then `.reload`.

Comment: i got error like ...                                                                                                lkd> .load ndiskd
lkd> !ndiskd.miniport 
    MiniDriver         Miniport            Name                                _
    
    .reload ndis.sys....
Type information missing error for DriverEntry
    Reload succeeded, but symbols aren't available.
    Below output maybe incomplete or incorrect until you fix your symbols.
    [Next link in list is not readable; aborting the list traversal]

Comment: @roger: Right now, there is a [known kernel symbol issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278634/is-there-a-known-issue-relating-to-windows-7-kernel-symbols)

Comment: this link is very useful worked for me  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windbg/yjBZdelvEU8